# Programmatically scrolling a word into view in a textview

Tags: android, scroll, textview, scrollview

I have TextView with a large amount of text, the user searches for something and I highlight the matches, however they may be way down the page, is there a way to scroll to the first match?

I looked all over google and did not seem to find anything relevant.

My Layout :

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/sclView">

    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/txtView"
              android:textSize="16sp"
              android:paddingTop="10dp"
              android:paddingLeft="20dp"
              android:paddingRight="20dp"
              android:paddingBottom="10dp"
              android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
              android:textColor="@color/TextGray"
              android:textIsSelectable="true"/>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming there's no horizontal scrolling. If there is, you can extrapolate from this answer. Seeing as you're highlighting the matches, I'm also going to assume you have the finding part down already. This means you should have at least a start position for the search string in the `CharSequence`.

Use [`Layout.getLineForOffset`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Layout.html#getLineForOffset%28int%29) to find the line for the string, then [`Layout.getLineTop`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Layout.html#getLineTop%28int%29) to get the position of the top of the line, then [`View.scrollTo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#scrollTo%28int,%20int%29) to scroll to your desired position. It should look something like this:

```
Layout layout = textView.getLayout();
scrollView.scrollTo(0, layout.getLineTop(layout.getLineForOffset(startPos)));
```

I haven't tried this out, so you might have to do something to deal with the padding that you've added, etc. but I would think the general idea should work.

Comment: worked for me! however I have many other views in the ScrollView so I had to do something like this `scrollView.scrollTo(0, layout.getLineTop(txtView.getTop() + layout.getLineForOffset(startPos)));` so txtView.getTop() gets the top position of the textView in pixels relative to its parent view and adds it to the getLineTop vertical position of the line you are looking for