# call scroll event on TextView Android?

Tags: java, android, events, scroll, textview

I have a textview and when i call the onTouch event, i want it to call his original scroll event.
Something like this:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, Event e){
    switch(event.getAction){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:{
            v.callOriginalScrollEvent(v,e);
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Any way to call the original scroll event?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21054528/programmatically-scrolling-a-word-into-view-in-a-textview this might be helpful to you

Comment: I want to keep the scroll effect, thats why i want to call the view scroll event, not simply use the scrollTo cause it losses the effect.