# Jump on the word highlighted inside ScrollView

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I have here code where it highlights all the words inside the TextView which is equal to the typed string. By pressing the buttons next/previous, It highlights the current word found.

What I'm trying to do is to go to the position of that word currently being highlighted.

I've added this code inside my onClick

```
myScroll.scrollBy(0, +20);
```

But it doesn't seem to be what im looking for

Also I've tried something like this

```
myScroll.scrollTo(0, selected); // getting the index of the highlighted word
                                // but it's not working
```

onClickListener to highlight next word

```
findViewById(R.id.next).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
 selected++;

 String text = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText)).getText().toString();
if(text.equals("") {}
else
  selected = changeTextView(details, text, selected);
}
});
```

method to highlight the text

```
   private int changeTextView(TextView tv, String target, int selected) {
     if(selected < 0 ) {
        selected = 0;
     }

    String bString = (String) tv.getText().toString();
    int startSpan = 0, endSPan = 0;
    Spannable spanRange = new SpannableString(bString);

    int currentIndex = 0;

    while(true) {
      startSpan = bString.indexOf(target, endSpan);
      endSpan = startSpan + target.lenght();

      boolean isLast = bString.indexOf(target, endSpan) < 0;
      if(startSpan < 0)
        break;

      ParcelableSpan span;
      if(currentIndex == selected || isLast && selected > currentIndex) {
          span = new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.LTGRAY);

          if(isLast && selected > currentIndex) {
            selected = currentIndex;
          }
        } else {
              span = new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW);
         }

        currentIndex++;
        spanRange.setSpan(
                  span,
                  startSpan,
                  endSpan,
                  Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
   }
    tv.setText(spanRange);

    if(currentIndex == 0) {
       return -1;
    } else {
     return selected;
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21054528/programmatically-scrolling-a-word-into-view-in-a-textview