# Scroll to Specific string in custom listview item

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-studio

I have a custom `ListView` which has `TextView` with long text.Now I want to scroll to specific String in `TextView`.[check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdhB2.png)

Please check the image.In prevoius activity if user select versus 9 it will scroll to versus 9.
Thanks

Comment: Are all items in a single row?

Comment: yes, all items are  in single row mean in single TextView.

Comment: Can you add item as a different row?

Comment: No,I have to add it in single row.In different row it is working perfect.Need solution for single row.

Comment: The items are not of uniform length too?

Comment: yes,length is also changing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically scrolling a word into view in a textview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21054528/programmatically-scrolling-a-word-into-view-in-a-textview)

Comment: I have tried but I have problem.  1) when i touch the textview it automatically scroll to the start of textview.  2) How to find the offset of specific string?

Comment: And it also shows the Empty space in the bottom of textview.