# How Do I Search For A Word In A Textview?

Tags: android, search, android-edittext, textview

Ok, I have an `EditText`, A `Search Button` And A `Textview` with a large scrollable text.

When I enter a word in `EditText` and press the `Search Button`, **the word gets highlighted**.Till this, it all works fine.
 But what I want is that when I enter a word and press the `button`, it should highlight the word and also move the camera to that particular word ( I think its called focusing in android), I don't want to scroll every time to find my highlighted word.Say my typed word is at the bottom of the text and is highlighted, I can't scroll it every time to find it, it's very irritating.So please help!

> So what I want is that when I search for a word it should get
>   highlighted and should also appear on the screen automatically without
>   me scrolling down or up.
>
> And One More thing, I want to unhighlight the word as soon as EditText
>   becomes empty

**Here Is My Code**

```js
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.xeoh.android.texthighlighter.TextHighlighter;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText search;
    TextView textView;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        search = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.search);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);


        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new TextHighlighter()
                        .setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFF00"))
                        .setForegroundColor(Color.RED)
                        .addTarget(textView)
                        .highlight(search.getText().toString(),TextHighlighter.BASE_MATCHER);


            }
        });













    }
}
```

```html
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/search"
                android:hint="Search"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Search"
                android:id="@+id/button"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/test"/>




        </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think this is really hard if not impossible to accomplish with the standard TextView. Using a unique long TextView you can't know where the string you are searching is placed and you can't retrieve the position of this string to scroll to that coordinates...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically scrolling a word into view in a textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21054528/programmatically-scrolling-a-word-into-view-in-a-textview)

Comment: what if i have multiple textviews,each textview has an id,can i then search for the the entire textview by the id,and display it on the screen

Comment: Maybe i was wrong reading the answer linked by @NSimon, i don't know if it can works for you but maybe you can give it a try at least

Comment: @FurqanHussain everything you need to scroll to the right position is given by the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21055657/4232337 
You know how to search/locate the right word/sentence inside your TextView(s). What the answer tells you is "scroll to the position of that TextView first. Then scroll to the position of the line where the found text is, given the result of **Layout.getLineForOffset** and **Layout.getLineTop**".

Comment: @NSimon and he need to take into account the textview position (and this depends by the used layout) and the padding added to the textview (if present)

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you have:

Layout:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="search!"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/textViewWrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/scrollableText"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </ScrollView>
```

Then in your code:

```
    scrollableText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scrollableText);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    textViewWrapper = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.textViewWrapper);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    scrollableText.setText(R.string.longText);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String criteria = editText.getText().toString();
            String fullText = scrollableText.getText().toString();
            if (fullText.contains(criteria)) {
                int indexOfCriteria = fullText.indexOf(criteria);
                int lineNumber = scrollableText.getLayout().getLineForOffset(indexOfCriteria);
                String highlighted = "<font color='red'>"+criteria+"</font>";
                fullText = fullText.replace(criteria, highlighted);
                scrollableText.setText(Html.fromHtml(fullText));

                textViewWrapper.scrollTo(0, scrollableText.getLayout().getLineTop(lineNumber));
            }
        }
    });
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            if (charSequence.length() == 0) {
                String fullText = scrollableText.getText().toString();
                fullText = fullText.replace("<font color='red'>", "");
                fullText = fullText.replace("</font>", "");
                scrollableText.setText(fullText);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```

where `longText` is some long text defined in your `strings.xml`. You may want to apply some other style on your text (as I did with `<font color='red'>`).

It should do the job. I've tested it on android 8 (Oreo) and it worked fine.

Comment: @FurqanHussain you're welcome. Please mark the answer as the correct answer.