# Go to text in a long scrollable TextView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, textview

I have a long scrollable TextView and I want to find a way on how I can bookmark a specific word by selecting it from the TextView and then able to scroll back to that word again by using a bookmark button and highlighting it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe that one help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46582552/how-do-i-search-for-a-word-in-a-textview

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Do I Search For A Word In A Textview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46582552/how-do-i-search-for-a-word-in-a-textview)

Comment: Hi, I actually want to be able to select a phrase from the textview and be able to bookmark it and then there'll be a dedicated bookmark button on the menubar that will go to that phrase when clicked.